# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController change Cancel button text to Done and still call delegate method?

Tags: ios

If the text itself can't be changed and the button needs to be replaced then please also explain how to make the delegate method

`- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker`

still get called from replacement button?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After some fiddling this worked:

Include `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in object `.h` file. Add the following to `.m` file:

```
- (void) showAddressBook {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    // use delegate to change cancel text to done on picker that pops up
    picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:true completion:nil];
}

// replace button now that controller is initialized
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController*)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if([navigationController isKindOfClass:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class]]) {

        UIBarButtonItem *obbi = navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;

        UIBarButtonItem *bbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:obbi.target action:obbi.action];
        navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = bbi;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me thanks, but the cancel button reappears after using the searchbar. To fix this I implemented the `UISearchDisplayDelegate` and in the `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` method I set `viewController.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;`